# JS How to measure size of FormData object?

Tags: javascript

I need some decision how to measure the size of FormData before send.
I haven't find anything in Internet on plain JS.
In formdata could be files and text fields

I need to know size in bytes and also length

Comment: What do you mean by "size"? The `.length` of properties keys or the size in bytes of attached data at values?

Comment: in bytes. and FormData doesn't have length

Comment: What's meant by the size, is what the `Content-Length` would be if you `.send` the `FormData`. There are irritating things like signed URLs that nitpick everything, big time. It's funny how certain people are that you don't need the size of a `FormData`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Array.from()`, `FormData.prototype.entries()` to iterate `.length` or `.size`

```js
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("text", "abc");
fd.append("file0", new Blob(["abcd"]));
fd.append("file1", new File(["efghi"], "file.txt"));

var res = Array.from(fd.entries(), ([key, prop]) => (
            {[key]: {
              "ContentLength": 
              typeof prop === "string" 
              ? prop.length 
              : prop.size
            }
          }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: If you want size in bytes replace prop.length with `new Blob([ prop ]).size` for strings.  Also, I think the size of the key text itself would technically need to be added to the size of the object along with any other overhead, not just the values.

Answer (score -1):

```
const getFormDataSize = (formData) => [...formData].reduce((size, [name, value]) => size + (typeof value === 'string' ? value.length : value.size), 0);


//Usage

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('field0', '...');
formData.append('field2', new File(['...'], 'file.txt'));
formData.append('field1', new Blob(['...']));

console.log('%i Bytes', getFormDataSize(formData));
```