# How do I get the size of form data?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

How can I get the size of FormData in JavaScript?
I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258208/js-how-to-measure-size-of-formdata-object), but its answer measures the size of the values only.

I want to send FormData with the `fetch` API, so, I need the overall size of FormData as Content-Length.

### Edit1

I want to send FormData like this:

```
let myhead = new Headers();
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("Name", "AAABBB");
// add several data... like picture, video, and so on.
myhead.append("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myhead.append("content-type", "multipart/form-data"); 
// I don't know which should I use.
myhead.append("content-length", "the value of size of formdata"); # 

fetch("http://localhost:8744/post", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    body: formdata,
    headers: myhead
});
```

### Edit2

I tried send to FormData with improved code like the following, but the browser keeps loading - it's taking too much time.

Improved version:

```
let myheaders = new Headers();
myheaders.append("connection", "close")
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("Hello", "World");

fetch("http://localhost:6788/nk", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    body: formdata,
    headers: myheaders
})
```

Comment: _"so I need overall size of FormData as Content-Length"_ You don't need that in order to send a FormData object through fetch api

Comment: What is your use case? Easy to iterate FormData values and if it is file get size

Comment: The Answer in the question, Is it  consider size of key?
I want to send FormData with fetch api, so I need to add Content-Length.

Comment: Content-Length header will be added automatically by the browser.Still not clear what problem is

Comment: I didn't know it will be added automatically.

Comment: Also a wrong `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and an invalid `multipart/form-data` seem to be added. They should be removed. `fetch` will add the proper header for you when using form data.

Comment: I tried sending data with improved code but it take too much load time.